# Floating divs within complex div structure

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm really close to getting this to look the way I want it :)

How do I :

1. make .tk17-speakings-ausgabe-daten-col1 and .tk17-speakings-ausgabe-daten-col2 start at the same horizontal level;
2. stop .tk17-speakings-ausgabe-daten-col2 wrapping around .tk17-speakings-ausgabe-datum?

Thanks in advance for any help!

```css
#tk17-speakings-termine-ausgabe ul{
    max-width:500px;
}
#tk17-speakings-termine-ausgabe li{
    display:inline-block;
    list-style-type:none;
    width:50%;
    padding-left:25%;
    padding-right:25%;
}
.tk17-speakings-ausgabe-datum{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    text-align:center;
    border:2px solid #c4d600;
    float:left;
    margin-right:40px;
} 
.tk17-speakings-ausgabe-datum h3{
    font:300 60px / 60px Lato;
    margin-bottom:0;
    margin-top:50px;
}
.tk17-speakings-ausgabe-datum h4{
    font:300 20px / 22px Lato;
    margin-top:0;
}
.tk17-speakings-ausgabe-title{
    margin-top:-20px;
}
.tk17-speakings-ausgabe-daten-container{
    margin-top:30px;
}
.tk17-speakings-ausgabe-daten-col1{
    float:left;
    width:20%;
}
.tk17-speakings-ausgabe-daten-col2{
    width:75%;
    margin-left:5%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="tk17-speakings-ausgabe-datum">
            <h3>11</h3>
            <h4>Juni<br>2017</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="tk17-speakings-ausgabe-title">
            <p><span class="tk17-spitzmarke">THEMA</span><br><span class="tk17-headlinetext-300-3033">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="tk17-speakings-ausgabe-daten-container">
            <div class="tk17-speakings-ausgabe-daten-col1">
                <p><span class="tk17-spitzmarke">VERANSTALTUNG</span><br><span class="tk17-fliess-400-1522">Veranstaltung GHI...</span></p>
                <p><span class="tk17-spitzmarke">ORT</span><br><span class="tk17-fliess-400-1522">Frankfurt, Xxxxxxxxxx<br><br><em>[offen]</em></span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="tk17-speakings-ausgabe-daten-col2 tk17-fliess-400-1522">
                <p><span class="tk17-spitzmarke">DETAILS</span><br></p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: not sure if I understand, like this? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dWKEoV

Comment: @MichaelCoker Almost, but without the scrollbars on .tk17-speakings-ausgabe-daten-col2!

Comment: I don't see scrollbars. this better? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/GmGaWX

Comment: @MichaelCoker Perfect. Easier than I thought ;) Post it and I'll mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content in the rows aren't horizontally aligned because of a margin in the `p` elements. And to keep `.tk17-speakings-ausgabe-daten-col2` from wrapping around, use `overflow: hidden`

```css
#tk17-speakings-termine-ausgabe li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 50%;
  padding-left: 25%;
  padding-right: 25%;
}

.tk17-speakings-ausgabe-datum {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #c4d600;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

.tk17-speakings-ausgabe-datum h3 {
  font: 300 60px / 60px Lato;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.tk17-speakings-ausgabe-datum h4 {
  font: 300 20px / 22px Lato;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.tk17-speakings-ausgabe-title {
  margin-top: -20px;
}

.tk17-speakings-ausgabe-daten-container {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.tk17-speakings-ausgabe-daten-col1 {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
}

.tk17-speakings-ausgabe-daten-col2 {
  margin-left: 5%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

p {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="tk17-speakings-ausgabe-datum">
            <h3>11</h3>
            <h4>Juni<br>2017</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="tk17-speakings-ausgabe-title">
            <p><span class="tk17-spitzmarke">THEMA</span><br><span class="tk17-headlinetext-300-3033">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="tk17-speakings-ausgabe-daten-container">
            <div class="tk17-speakings-ausgabe-daten-col1">
                <p><span class="tk17-spitzmarke">VERANSTALTUNG</span><br><span class="tk17-fliess-400-1522">Veranstaltung GHI...</span></p>
                <p><span class="tk17-spitzmarke">ORT</span><br><span class="tk17-fliess-400-1522">Frankfurt, Xxxxxxxxxx<br><br><em>[offen]</em></span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="tk17-speakings-ausgabe-daten-col2 tk17-fliess-400-1522">
                <p><span class="tk17-spitzmarke">DETAILS</span><br></p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```